# aio_write() always fails with error EINVAL

Tags: c++, posix

I'm trying to use the aio_write(1) function. The code below is my program. However, the aio_write() always return EINVAL.

I read the error reason of the EINVAL:  One or more of aio_offset, aio_reqprio, aio_nbytes are invalid. However, I cannot figure out the reason why the value I set is incorrect!

Could anyone help?

**[UPDATE]** This code is compilable and runnable! But the result is incorrect! I think it's because the buffer_out is overwritten before it's written into the file. Is there any better and neater way to do it? aio_error(1) can be queried, but it's like busy-waiting and hurt the performance.

Is there any better way to avoid the buffer overwritten and keep the speed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <aio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <errno.h>
using namespace std;

#define true 1
#define false 0

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int offset = 0, fd_offset = 0;
    int slen = 0;
    char* buffer, *buffer_out;
    int buffer_size = 30;
    int is_first_write = true;

    struct aiocb aio_param;
    int fd_out = open("result.log", O_APPEND | O_RDWR);    

    buffer = (char*) malloc(buffer_size);
    buffer_out = (char*) malloc(buffer_size);
    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
    memset(buffer_out, 0, buffer_size);

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "LOG *****" << i << "-" << "********\n";
        slen = strlen(ss.str().c_str());
        //cout<<"written to offset: " << offset << endl; 
        //buffer is not large enough to take the current string
        if(offset + slen > buffer_size)
        {
        //write the current buffer content (< 4K) into the file
            memset(&aio_param, 0, sizeof(aio_param));
            aio_param.aio_fildes = fd_out;
            aio_param.aio_offset = fd_offset;
            while( aio_error(&aio_param) != 0 && is_first_write == false ) {cout << "wait for the previous one finish" <<endl;}
            aio_param.aio_buf = memcpy(buffer_out, buffer, buffer_size); //the buffer_out has to be written before it's copied to again!
            aio_param.aio_nbytes = offset;
            //aio_offset = ? should be the end of file for O_APPEND mode
            aio_param.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_NONE;
            if( aio_write(&aio_param) == -1 )
            {
                cout<<"ERR: aio_write()==-1"<<endl;
                cout<<"errno:" << errno <<endl;
                return 1;
            }else{
                is_first_write = false;
                fd_offset += offset;
                cout<<"aio_write()" << offset << " bytes succeed at file offset " << fd_offset<<endl;
                offset = 0;
             //   sleep(1);
            //clean the buffer
                memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
            }
        }
        //write the current string to the buffer 
        memcpy(buffer + offset, ss.str().c_str(), slen);
        offset += slen;
    }
    close(fd_out);
    return 0;

}
```

The incorrect result is:

```
LOG *****2-********
LOG *****4-********
LOG *****4-********
LOG *****4-********
LOG *****5-********
LOG *****5-********
LOG *****6-********
LOG *****8-********
```

**(It should be from 0 to 8 without any duplication.)**

Comment: Why is the assignment to `aio_offset` commented out?

Comment: And why are you putting `offset` rather than `buffer_size` into `aio_nbytes`? `offset` is initially 0, and a value of 0 for `nbytes` probably (I haven't checked this) warrants `EINVAL`.

Comment: I used gdb to check, offset is not 0 when it call aio_write()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not assigning all values of `aio_param` (and it is uninitialized on the stack), I recommend zeroing it out before use:

```
memset(&aio_param, 0, sizeof(aio_param));
```

Also, I'm thinking you probably want to set `aio_offset` ?

Comment: HI @Jonathon, Thank you very much! After I set the param to 0, it works for some loop. but after iteration for 4 times, it reports error: aio_write()20 bytes succeed!
aio_write()40 bytes succeed!
aio_write()60 bytes succeed!
aio_write()80 bytes succeed!
*** glibc detected *** ./aio_write: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000013a6070 ***

Comment: @MikeXu It's painful to discern your error messages when put in a comment. Instead, you should edit the original question to include this new information.

Comment: Hi @Jonathon, I updated my question. It can run now. but the buffer_out is overwitten and cause the result is incorrect.